# Calling parent struct inherited methods

Tags: c++11, pointers, inheritance, struct, multiple-inheritance

I have a struct A that inherits from other classes (which I'm not allowed to change). Inside A and it's methods I can call inherited methods (lets say A_method(int i), for example) without problem but when I tried to write a nested struct (lets say In) and call A_method(int i) and there is were I'm stuck.

The initial code looks like this, and I can't change it, is some kind of college assigment.

```
#include "Player.hh"
struct A : public Player {
  static Player* factory () {
    return new A;
  }

  virtual void play () {
  }
};

RegisterPlayer(PLAYER_NAME);
```

Then I tried this:

```
#include "Player.hh"
struct A : public Player {
  static Player* factory () {
    return new A;
  }

  //My code
  struct In {
    int x;
    void do_smthing() {
      A_method(x);
    }
  }

  virtual void play () {
  }
};

RegisterPlayer(PLAYER_NAME);
```

Ok, from a beginning I knew I could't do this, for In to see it's parent class it should have a pointer to it but In is a often instantiated object in my code and I wanted to avoid passing `this` constantly to a constructor so I tried this aproach:

```
#include "Player.hh"
struct A : public Player {
  static Player* factory () {
    return new A;
  }

  //My code

  static struct Aux
        A* ptr;
        Aux(A* _p) { ptr = _p; }
    } aux;

  struct In {
    int x;
    void do_smthing() {
      aux.ptr->A_method(x);
    }
  }

  virtual void play () {
    //the idea is to call do_smthing() here.
  }
};

RegisterPlayer(PLAYER_NAME);
```

What I want to avoid (if possible) is something like this:

```
struct In {
  int x;
  A* ptr;

  In (A* _p) : ptr(_p) {}

  void do_smthing() {
    ptr->A_method(x);
  }
}
```

The main reason for this: I have more struct definitions and they they are instantiated multiple times through the rest of the (omitted) code, and I don't like the idea of seeing `In(this)` so many times.

I don't know if I'm completly missing something or what I want to do it's just not possible... Please ask for clarifications if necessary.

(Also, performance is kind of critical, my code will be tested with limited CPU time so I kinda have to avoid expensive approachs if possible. Using C++11)

Comment: Also, I really don't know if the question title aproachs this question well enough, I would apreciate any suggestion or edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way you can skip passing the `this` pointer. Instead, you could create a helper function in A:

```
template <typename InnerType, typename ...Params>
InnerType makeInner(Params&&... params)
{
    return InnerType(this, std::forward<Params>(params)...);
}
```

Then you can use

```
auto * a = A::factory();
auto inner = a->makeInner<A::In>();
```

I have some suggestions which are not directly related to you question but may help:

- `A::facotry()` returns a `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of raw pointer
- Try to describe what problem you are trying to solve. I have a strong feeling that there can be a better design other than creating many nested structs.
- I don't see passing a `this` pointer could have any impact on the performance. The more important thing is to identify the path that is latency-sensitive and move expensive operations out of those paths.

Comment: That's been very helpful!  About the design proach, since it's a "competitive college assigment", I should do and decide everything by my self, otherwise I could be disclassified! I'll consider avoiding nested structs tho, thanks again